# Class instantiation using the Autowired annotation

Tags: java, annotations

Is its advisable to instantiate the class using `@Autowired` annotation like below.

```
@Autowired
public static Car = new Car();
```

Comment: `Autowired` initializes it for you, so it doesn't make sense to initialize it yourself. If you want to use Dependency Injection you shouldn't be initializing autowired resources yourself.

Comment: The whole point of autowired is that you don't have to do the = new .. part.

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1**

If you are trying to autowire an attribute like following:

```
@Autowired
public Car car;
```

then Spring will try to search for a Bean definition in Spring context and will also instantiate it, hence no need to again invoke constructor.

**Case 2**

If you are getting confused with constructor autowire like following:

```
@Autowired
public Driver(License license){
        this.license = license;
}
```

Here, it is trying to get the Bean of "License" class autowired, and it is not autowireing Driver.

In your case, I feel it is case 1.

If you are trying to set it manually cause you are seeing it as not initialized, then check the spring application context configuration file/class. You will need to have something like following in it:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.packagename" />
```

If using AppConfig class then:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.test.packagename")
public class AppConfig {

}
```

Also, make sure that your spring core is deployed in lib where it is executing.
Also check that you are instantiating the class by using Spring application context as follows:

```
AbstractApplicationContext  context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);     
 Car car= (Application)context.getBean("car");
```

Try to refer this: http://websystique.com/spring/spring-dependency-injection-annotation-beans-auto-wiring-using-autowired-qualifier-resource-annotations-configuration/

Happy coding DBZ fan :-)

Comment: Yes you are right  but the car class is given as @Component annotation when i tried to find the null pointer exception using debug mode the car variable is null.

Comment: Its ok, @Component annotation marks a java class as a bean so the component-scanning mechanism of spring can pick it up and pull it into the application context. Or you can have an application context xml to define your bean.

Also you will need to have something like following in your application  context xml.
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.howtodoinjava.demo.service" />
So that the spring will know which packages it should scan in order to find components.

Comment: <context:component-scan base-package="com.qvc.customerservice.app.oecs.ordercreate"/> but still my i cannot find the object in the debug mode or it throws exception null in live running

Comment: Might be your spring core is not deployed in lib where it is executing.

Comment: spring core is in my maven library

Comment: Just found I forgot to write the configuration class for application context, hope this could be issue